# Why reverse osmosis does not cause perpetual motion?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, perpetual-motion, osmosis

In **reverse osmosis**, water molecules flow from dense solution to pure water under external pressure.
***But how does this process prevents perpetual motion?***

Consider the following example.
Salt water level will raise by height $h$ due to concentration of solvent (left figure).
When achieving equilibrium, if we use the same concentration of the solution to create another condition (right figure) that pure water and salt water have the same height $h_1$.
By taking large value of $h_1$, reverse osmosis condition can be achieved and pure water level will be raised (higher than salt water). However, if this can happen, we could redirect the pure water into salt water to create perpetual motion.

I have no doubt of the law of conservation of energy, but still not quite understand what is the reason behind.
Is it the case that this water level $h_1$ can never be achieved ? or the equations just cannot be simplified as in the picture?
I hope someone in the field of thermodynamics can give more insights behind.

[image]

Comment: You lose a lot of energy in pressure drop across the reverse-osmosis membrane.

Comment: A perpetual motion machine necessarily requires 100% efficiency (aka no energy losses).  Big pressure drop through a membrane represents a lot of lost energy, as dimensional analysis indicates that pressure is not only force per unit area, it is also energy per unit volume.

Comment: Please ask one question only, not two.

Comment: I have no doubt of energy conservation, but just wonder whether such conditions can be achieved, if so, what is the new stable equilibrium?